# Kernel panic after installing Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, kernel, boot-repair

I have installed Ubuntu 16.10, but I can't boot it. It's a shame as I have looked at it and like the way it is. I went for the install alongside Windows 10, and I just don't know what to do.

I have this error that came up:

```
(0.535703) end kernel panic - not syncing: vfs: unable to mount root fs on unknown - block (0,0)
```

After I searched the internet, I downloaded the "boot-repair-disk-64bit" and ran it, and it said that the boot sector was fixed, but to no avail.

I have used Rufus to put the "ubuntu-16.10-desktop-amd64 ISO" onto a USB and finally burned it to a DVD.

I am totally lost and being new to this and not much of a computer wizard, I would still love to have the system working properly, so any help in layman's terms would be really good.

Comment: Go for 16.04 anyways, 16.10 was just released and likely to have more issues.

Comment: Thank you @M.Becerra  I will try 16.04 and see how it goes. I found out how to remove the partitions from the previous version and now I will start again. Fingers crossed :)

Comment: After I did a boot repair and all is good now but in 16.04 I just could not get the wifi setup even after several hours of reading so I redid the partitions and installed 16.10 and all is good, fantastic so far anyway. :)